# C# Finding the Mode

Tags: c#, mode

In my program I'm trying to find the `Mode` from a list of integers.  Logically wise my program is correct.  However when I try to print out the `Mode` I get the following message `"Mode: System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.Int32]`.  The outcome I was expecting to print is "`Mode: 2, 7`" since these 2 numbers occur 3 times in the list of integers.  What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Mode
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test();
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            int[] values = { 1, 6, 4, 7, 9, 2, 5, 7, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8, 1, 3, 8, 2 };
            List<int> mode = new List<int>();

            mode = Mode(values);
            Console.WriteLine("Mode: {0}", mode);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static List<int> Mode(int[] values)
        {
            int[] sorted = new int[values.Length];
            values.CopyTo(sorted, 0);
            Array.Sort(sorted);

            List<int> result = new List<int>();
            var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            int max = 0;
            foreach (int num in sorted)

            {
                if (counts.ContainsKey(num))
                    counts[num] = counts[num] + 1;
                else
                    counts[num] = 1;
            }

            foreach (var key in counts.Keys)
            {
                if (counts[key] > max)
                {
                    max = counts[key];
                    result.Add(max);
                }
            }

            return result;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user DesertFox mentioned properly.
You are trying to print a list. Intead of that, as per your requirement, make it as a single `string` using  `String.Join`.

Modify your test method like below

```
    static void Test()
    {
        try
        {
            int[] values = { 1, 6, 4, 7, 9, 2, 5, 7, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8, 1, 3, 8, 2 };
            List<int> mode = new List<int>();

            mode = Mode(values);
            Console.WriteLine("Mode: {0}", String.Join(", ", mode));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Output

[image]

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `string.Format` and object from a reference type class that doesn't have a custom `.ToString()` implementation. I recommend the use of `String.Join` (reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx))

**C#**

```
Console.WriteLine("Mode: {0}", String.Join(", ", mode));
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the items in the list rather than the list itself.